# How to enable Auto Complete feature in PHPmyadmin 4.1.14 SQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm using WAMP PHPMyadmin version 4.1.14 and l want to enable autocomplete feature.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

append `$cfg['EnableAutocompleteForTablesAndColumns']=true;` before `?>` to `\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` file and restart WAMP services.